# How to map_err file.open?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to map the error of a file open like this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum BitstreamCreationError {
    FileNotFound(String),
    Unknown(String),
}

fn main() {
    let file = std::fs::File::open("my/path").map_err(|e| match e {
        Err(std::io::Error{..}) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::NotFound => BitstreamCreationError::FileNotFound,
        _ => BitstreamCreationError::Unknown(format!("{:?}",e)),
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ec47b481b63ce6ea075792ec816f9a75)

so I can return with the `?` in case of error. However I'm getting this:

Error:

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> /home/dev/orwell/liborwell/src/core/bitstream_rtsp_client.rs:81:18
   |
78 |           let file = File::open(url.clone()).map_err(|e| match e {
   |  ________________________________________________________-
79 | |             //e if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::NotFound => BitstreamCreationError::FileNotFound,
80 | |             Err(std::io::Error{..}) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::NotFound => BitstreamCreationError::FileNotFound,
   | |                                                                                    ------------------------------------ this is found to be of type `fn(std::string::String) -> BitstreamCreationError {BitstreamCreationError::FileNotFound}`
81 | |             _ => BitstreamCreationError::Unknown(format!("{:?}",e)),
   | |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn item, found enum `BitstreamCreationError`
82 | |         });
   | |_________- `match` arms have incompatible types
```

Why it says that the type of the first match option is `fn(std::string::String) -> BitstreamCreationError {BitstreamCreationError::FileNotFound}`? This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two issues. One is that `map_err` passes its closure the error instance, not the error wrapped in a `Result`, so you should match on `std::io::Error { .. }` and not on `Err(...)`. The other is that both your enum variants require a string, so you should construct `FileNotFound` with `BitstreamCreationError::FileNotFound(<some string>)`. If you omit both the string and the parentheses, it looks like you're referring to the *function* `BitstreamCreationError::FileNotFound` which constructs a `BitstreamCreationError` from a string, and that's why the error message refers to `fn(String) -> BitstreamCreationError`.

The corrected code might look like this:

```
let file = std::fs::File::open("my/path").map_err(|e| match e {
    std::io::Error { .. } if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::NotFound => {
        BitstreamCreationError::FileNotFound(format!("{:?}", e))
    }
    _ => BitstreamCreationError::Unknown(format!("{:?}", e)),
});
```